# ansible loop condition, does like instead of equal when check item in a list

Tags: ansible

assume I have test.yml and a variable: packages in command line to specify which yml need to run, test.yml is as below:

```
- include: "{{item}}.yml"
  with_items:
    - a
    - a_a
    - b
    - c
  when: "'{{item}}' in packages"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item
```

it seems when ansible check the condition "'{{item}}' in packages" it is using like but not equal. e.g. if I run:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts -e hosts=myhost test.yml -e packages = [a_a, b]
```

Anisible will run a_a.yml, b.yml and a.yml as well (don't want a.yml to run).  how could I change the way ansible check the condition to fix it (change name is not a sustainable way)?

Comment: There are tags and roles already implemented in Ansible for such use cases. Why do you need to invent workarounds for non-existent problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: don't use curly brackets in `when` statement – it's already Jinja2 expression.

```
when: item in packages
```

Second: `in` operator checks that one list(item) is a part of another list and because strings in Python may be treated as lists, `in` operator is often used to check for pattern in string like: `'pattern' in str_var`.

Third: `-e` argument for `ansible-playbook` accepts two form of values: `key=value` and `JSON`, and there is a note about this in the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line):

> **Note**
>   Values passed in using the key=value syntax are interpreted as strings. Use the JSON format if you need to pass in anything that shouldn’t be a string (Booleans, integers, floats, lists etc).

Combining all this together, you should fix your when statement and pass extra vars as JSON:

```
-e '{"packages":["a_a","b"]}'
```